# Find the remainder when $x^{1001}$ is divided by $x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1.$

Tags: polynomials

Find the remainder when $x^{1001}$ is divided by $x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1.$

Source: AoPS Alcumus

---

I tried factoring $\frac{x^{1001}}{x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1}$ to get $\frac{x^{1001}}{(x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)}$. However, I'm not sure what to do after this. Can someone please give a solution? Thanks.

Comment: You should say something about *why* you factored the bottom line. For example, have you come across similar questions where this was the first step (if so, you should mention/explain the approach in this question)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a start \begin{align} q(x)&:=x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1 \\&= (x^2+1)^2+x(x^2+1) \\ &= (x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)
\end{align}
Now write $$x^{1001} = k(x)q(x) + ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\;\;\;(*)$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are real. Now note that $q(i)=q(\omega)=0$ where $\omega = {-1+i\sqrt{3}\over 2 }$ is a 3rd root of unity.

- Plug $x=i$ in $(*)$ and we get $$i = -ai-b+ci+d\implies \boxed{b=d\wedge c-a=1}$$
- Plug $x=\omega $ in $(*)$ and we get $$\omega^2 = a+b\omega ^2 +c\omega +d$$

Since $\omega ^2 = -\omega -1$ we have $$-\omega = c -b\omega +c\omega$$ so $c=0$ and $b=1$ and thus remainder is $$-x^3+x^2+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x^2+x+1)(x-1)=x^3-1$ and $(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=x^4-1$, and that
$$x^{12}-1=\frac{\Phi_{12}}{x-1}\cdot(x^3-1)(x^4-1)=(x^4-x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2+1)(x^2-1).$$
So we can first divide $x^{1001}$ by $x^{12}-1$, and then divide the remainder by $x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1$.

Of course $1001\equiv5\pmod{12}$ and so all that is left is to divide $x^5$ by $x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1$, which is not a lot of work, as
$$(x-1)(x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1)=x^5+x^3-x^2-1.$$
This shows that the remainder is $-x^3+x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

A higher-level plug-and-chug answer, if you know some ring theory:

$x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1 = (x^2 + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$, so by the chinese remainder theorem we have a ring isomorphism

$$\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2+1)} \times \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2 + x + 1)} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}.$$

Specifically, the isomorphism we have in mind is

$$\varphi = p \mapsto (p(i), p(\zeta)) : \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1)} \to \mathbb{C}^2$$

where $\zeta$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity. Now we compute

$$\varphi(x^{1001}) = (i^{1001}, \zeta^{1001}) = (i, \zeta^2)$$

meaning that the residue of $x^{1001}$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is $x$ and the residue in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is $x^2$. Next we find a Bézout identity for the pair $(x^2 + 1, x^2 + x + 1)$ by running the Euclidean algorithm:

$$1 = (1+x)(x^2 + 1) - x(x^2 + x + 1).$$

Finally, we have that the residue of $x^{1001}$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1)$ is

$$x^2(1+x)(x^2+1) + x(-x)(x^2+x+1) = x^5 \\ = x(x^4) = x(-x^3-2x^2-x-1) = -x^4-2x^3-x^2-x \\ = -(-x^3-2x^2-x-1)-2x^3-x^2-x = \boxed{-x^3+x^2+1}.$$